# WiX Heat tool, create Component with Win64 attribute

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Is there a way to generate file using `heat` tool which will have `Win64` attribute in `Component` sections?

The problem is, in my 64-bit installer most of the files are 32-bit components, which must be marked as `Win64="no"` in `Component` entries. I use `heat` tool to generate them, so additional manual step is since required, and this brokes our automated build.

**UPDATE**: The short answer is "no" (which is marked as answer), I suppose I will just go with some additinal tool which will do the job.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Heat.exe` doesn't have a switch for this, but `candle.exe` does. Feed `-arch x64` to the command line of `candle.exe`, and it will set platform defaults for package, components, etc.

BTW, the question was originally asked [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/heat-exe-Add-attribute-Win64-quot-yes-quot-to-Component-elements-td4947690.html).

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is not the functionality I need.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer then? :) I suppose it you specify your requirements in more detail, people here could help you

Comment: Well, it answers my question: `heat` can't do that. I've updated the question with some details.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but was just searching for the same issue and this came up.

I discovered you can still use Heat if you add the "-arch x64" to the Compiler Additional Parameters under "Tool Settings" in the Wix project properties.